# Explicacion de division en lua

Tags: script, lua

alguien me puede explicar la funcion del siguiente codigo lua no logro entender bien?

```
num = 10

if num % 2 == 0 
    then 
        print("es par")
    else
        print("no es par")
    end
```

Comment: num % 2 devuelve el resto de la división de num entre 2, por lo que si es 0, es par.

Answer (score 3):

El operador módulo (`%`) devuelve el [resto de la división](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resto) entre el número a la izquierda del operador y el número a la derecha del operador.

Cuando un número `A` es divisible por un número `B`, el resto de la división entre `A` y `B` es cero, por definición sabemos que los números pares son aquellos que son divisibles entre dos, así pues:

```
num = 10

if num % 2 == 0            -- Es 'num' divisible entre dos?
    then 
        print("es par")    -- Lo es! Ergo: es par.
    else
        print("no es par") -- No lo es, ergo: es impar.
    end
```